# Outer Glow around 2D object using three.js

Tags: 2d, three.js, webgl, shadow, glow

I have a screen full of tiled/stacked triangular pieces of 2D "paper" using three.js. The objects are added at random positions/intervals and are positioned *very* close to each other on the z-axis so they don't stack too high.

I have the lighting exactly how I want it for the bump-map and *shape* shadows... but the shapes themselves have no **cast** shadow. This is because the objects are too close together to get the desired effect, and I don't want to mess up the current light source. Cast shadows would also be only in one direction (opposite the light source)... whereas I am attempting to get a shadow (actually an outer-glow) around the entire piece of paper.

I am therefore trying to create an outer-glow or at least find a reasonable solution to *fake* soft drop shadows around the entire shape. I have attached an image illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish... in essence it's like a CSS box-shadow effect.

```
box-shadow:  0px 0px 18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

[image: Outer Glow]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**tl;dr: Trying to create a outer-glow around 2D shapes in three.js**

Comment: Would Ambient Occlusion work for what you're trying to do? As in this example?
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_ssao

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I might have — but that was seven years ago... so I don't remember. Sorry.